# Update - Firebird com Inner Join

Tags: firebird, sql-update

Preciso realizar um Update em vários registros ao mesmo tempo, estou tentando otimizar o processo!

```
SELECT tei.id_identificador, tes.uni_medida, tep.qtd_atual
FROM tb_estoque tes
INNER JOIN tb_est_tipo_item_sis tis ON tes.id_tipoitem = tis.id_tipoitem
INNER JOIN tb_est_identificador tei ON tes.id_estoque = tei.id_estoque
INNER JOIN tb_est_produto tep ON tei.id_identificador = tep.id_identificador;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o Select acima obtive os dados, porem ao tentar realizar o Update retorna erro!

Estou tentando com a seguinte instrução:

```
update tb_estoque, tb_est_produto
inner join tb_est_tipo_item_sis on tb_estoque.id_tipoitem = tb_est_tipo_item_sis.id_tipoitem
inner join tb_est_identificador on tb_estoque.id_estoque = tb_est_identificador.id_estoque
left join tb_est_produto on tb_est_identificador.id_identificador = tb_est_produto.id_identificador
set
    tb_estoque.uni_medida = [valor_pretendido],
    tb_est_produto.qtd_atual = [valor_pretendido]
where
    tb_est_identificador.id_identificador = [condicao_pretendida];
```

Erro:

> "Invalid token. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Token
>   unknown - line 1, column 18. ,."

Comment: você esta executando isso no firebird, mysql, ou ambos?

Comment: @ErickLuz Estou utilizando o IBEXPERT, Firebird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Firebird você não consegue realizar esta façanha.
A sintaxe do do update dele é:

```
update NOME_TABELA set
NOME_CAMPO = VALOR
where xyz = xyz
```

O `JOIN` tera que ser com sub-select após o `WHERE`

[Fonte](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-update.html)

Comment: Pode aplicar um exemplo com base na tabela que coloquei na imagem?